# Can you refer a tutorial that will help me learn attaching adobe flash in a website using dreamweaver?

Tags: html, flash-cs5, dreamweaver

can you share some links to any tutorials that can help me learn basics of adobe flash cs5 and attach it on an html file using dreamweaver cs5.  I've been watching tutorials on Youtube, but if you have any adobe flash and dreamweaver tutorials that would be a big help. Thanks a lot ^_^

I hope i won't get any negatives here, i just want to hear tips from you guys because i don't have any idea right now... any tips will help a lot, or any keywords that can be googled up... thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try here:

http://layersmagazine.com/adding-flash-files-to-a-webpage-in-dreamweaver.html

Answer (score 1):

This site has a few: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Dreamweaver/Dreamweaver-and-Flash/1
(e.g., [this one](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Using-Image-Viewer-Flash-Element-Dreamweaver-MX/10864) or [this other one](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Add-Flash-to-your-Webpage-in-Dreamweaver/25139).

A couple more here: http://www.entheosweb.com/dreamweaver/default.asp

Comment: @Aleadam... thank you very much... this is an informative site :)

Comment: @Aleadam... i love the http://www.entheosweb.com/dreamweaver/default.asp this is such a big help for a beginner at adobe dreamweaver like me